# CSS parsing error with font face in javafx

Tags: java, css, javafx, stylesheet

I am using a tableview and would like to edit the font inside of it, however since tableview cannot implement a custom font with it's "setStyle" I am forced to rely on CSS

CSS code:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: '8BIT WONDER';
    src: url('8BITWONDERNominal.ttf');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

//Style of entire tableView
.table-view{
    -fx-font-family: "8BIT WONDER" ;
    -fx-text-alignment: center;
}

//Style of each column in the tableView
.table-view .table-column{
    -fx-font-size: 15px;  
}

//Style of each table cell
.table-view .table-cell{
    -fx-font-size: 12px;
    -fx-alignment: center;
}
```

Java line calling the CSS:

```
leaderScene.getStylesheets().add("leaderboard.css");
```

The CSS is parsing and is loading, the fonts and styles perfectly display on the table however the terminal still gives this error reguardless

```
WARNING: CSS Error parsing 
file:/D:/Overhaul%20with%20Leaderboard/Overhaul/leaderboard.css: Unexpected 
TOKEN [:] at [4,15]
Mar 29, 2018 10:21:45 AM com.sun.javafx.css.StyleManager 
loadStylesheetUnPrivileged
INFO: Could not load @font-face font 
[file:/D:/Overhaul%20with%20Leaderboard/Overhaul/8BITWONDERNominal.ttf]
Mar 29, 2018 10:33:21 AM com.sun.javafx.css.StyleManager 
loadStylesheetUnPrivileged
```

If there isn't a fix, is there a way to allow the terminal to ignore this error since the css is being loaded and functions correctly?